# Make the movement of the player as wanted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am creating a 2D space shooter game. I am not a beginner anymore in unity c# but still have some problems. I want to make the movement of the ship as in one web game: http://www.onemotion.com/flash/asteroids-game/
Play it by clicking on arrow keys to move. 
What I have got till now is a simple moving and turning :

```
void FixedUpdate () 
{
    float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float Vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    rb.velocity = transform.up * Vertical * Speed;
    transform.Rotate(0.0f,0.0f,Horizontal * RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The script is bigger but this part answers for moving please help me make the movement as in that game, I tried a lot of times, I tried different things but then I deleted them and came here because I am loosing too much time on this but I want to understand how to do it, thank you very much!

Comment: Other users are reluctant to do your work for you. There are plenty of Unity C# tutorials that you can find and read through to understand the basic concepts behind the game you have linked.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that my wrok can be done by me but I have tried till now to do it,  it has been already 8 hours I am trying to fix it, and I really need help

Answer (score 1):

I found out how , just use

```
RigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * speed * Vertical);
```

Also you can change the mass of the rigid body like this it will work perfectly.